# FxCop not working in TeamCity

Tags: fxcop, teamcity-7.1

While running FxCop as Build Step in Team City getting following error:
* Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid target file must be specified.
However, all Rules Dll's are loaded.
Here is the error log:

```
[23:39:07][Step 5/5] Used custom FxCop home directory 
[23:39:07][Step 5/5] Starting: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" 
                        /forceoutput /gac /ignoregeneratedcode "/project:branches/PaninRoot/LatestCode/TechnicalHelp/Panin List Of Rules.FxCop" 
                        /out:C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\fxcop-output-829310073154064004\fxcop-result.xml
[23:39:07][Step 5/5] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\39c68aea6b50c527 
[23:39:09][Step 5/5] Microsoft (R) FxCop Command-Line Tool, Version 10.0 (10.0.30319.1) X86 
[23:39:09][Step 5/5] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, All Rights Reserved.
[23:39:09][Step 5/5] 
[23:39:09][Step 5/5] Loading branches/PaninRoot/LatestCode/TechnicalHelp/Panin List Of Rules.FxCop...
[23:39:09][Step 5/5] Loaded DesignRules.dll...
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] Loaded NamingRules.dll...
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] Loaded PerformanceRules.dll...
[23:39:10][Step5/5] Loaded SecurityRules.dll...
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] Loaded UsageRules.dll... 
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] * Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] target file must be specified.
[23:39:10][Step 5/5] * 1 total analysis engine exceptions.
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Writing report toC:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\fxcop-output-829310073154064004\fxcop-result.xml...
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Done:00:00:03.1101779
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Process exited with code 1
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] FxCop return code (1): ANALYSIS_ERROR
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Analysis errors ignored as 'Fail on analysis errors' option unchecked
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Publishing artifacts
[23:39:11][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish[C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\fxcop-output-829310073154064004\fxcopresult.xml=>.teamcity/FxCop/] 
[23:39:11][Publishing artifacts] Sending C:/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/fxcop-output-829310073154064004/fxcop-result.xml 
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Importing inspection results 
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] FxCop error: Keyword=CA0052 Kind=Engine Type=Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException No targets were selected. 
[23:39:11][Step 5/5] Skipped html report generation since not requested 
[23:39:11]Publishing internal artifacts 
[23:39:11][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file 
[23:39:11]Total:0(+0 -0)Errors: 0(+0 -0) 
[23:39:11]Build finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `branches/PaninRoot/LatestCode/TechnicalHelp/Panin List Of Rules.FxCop` project file is causing the problem.  The first thing to check would be whether its paths to the target files (the assemblies you want to analyze) are relative or absolute.  If they're absolute, chances are that they don't match the paths on the build server.